# Deploying a different index page using Vercel with json-server

Tags: javascript, vercel, json-server

I am trying to deploy a pet project application of mine to Vercel. This application uses vanilla JavaScript along with `json-server` to fake a REST API endpoint for videos. The endpoint is solely for consumption purposes, and indeed, the application includes an index file located at `./public/index.html`. To configure `json-server`, I initiated the process by executing the commands `npm init -y` followed by `npm install json-server`. In the root directory of my project, I created the `server.js` file containing the following code:

```js
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('./backend/videos.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
});
```

I also added the "start" script into my `package.json` like the following:

```
{
  "name": "vidflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.4"
  }
}
```

And finally, I added the `vercel.json` with the following code:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": ["./backend/videos.json"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "server.js"
    }
  ]

}
```

After deploying it to Vercel the endpoint is working as expected but the index page is set `json-server` index page telling me that the `json-server` is successfully running, and that's not what I want. I want to display my index page from `./public/index.html`. How can I do that?